# How to sort groups based upon recent message in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

**Goal**: show the list of groups based upon the recent message and when a new message comes, update the chat group list.

**Firebase Structure:**

[image: firebase_structure_user_and_groups]

Left one structure represents **user model**: Basically under student key, there is a list of the student then its details along with group ids in which he/she participated.

Right one structure represents the **group detail model**: Under chat_group key, there is a list of groups with details and also recent message timing.

**Solution Tried:**

Fetch the group id from the student using the onChildAdded method of firebase DB one by one then fetch its group details using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent method, then store in the list and every time sort it using sort method of array list and then call notifyDataSetChanged method of recyclerview adapter.

**Problem with this approach**: Too time-consuming and as the number of groups increases processing time also increases.

Comment: Why you don't use directly chat_group to sort it based on recent_message_timeStamp?

Comment: @IslamAhmed because from the user model I get the list of group ids in which the user has signed up for.

Comment: Okay, So what is the problem if you replace CHAT_GROUPS_ID with the group details model .. like that .. student >> student1 >>chat_group_id >> its details ?

Comment: It is a long operation, like if a group has 50 members then each time a message send, need to update the recent message timestamp and other details too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to add a new key to the **group details model** for the students signed up , like that

```
SignedStudents : "student1 , student2 , student3"
```

Then you will read data from **chat_group** directly `orderedByChild("recent_message_timeStamp")` , then you have to filter it locally to get the groups only related to the specific student to add it to your list like that

```
String students = model.getStudents();
if (students.contains("student1")) addGroupToYourList();
```